# How to switch between unity scenes in android project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality application, using unity3d via vuforia plugin.

- The app should play a video playback when a target is detected.
- Targets will be images from scholar book.
- My videos are in three languages (arabic, english, french), my app should play the appropriate video referencing to the selected language button.
  To do that, I've created three scenes, one for each language, and I assigned the targets with the videos.

My question is:

- In Android, how to run the appropriate scene according to the clicked
  button?

Comment: Did you had problems using Application.LoadLevel()?

Comment: I want to control the scene from eclipse not from unity.
Is there any possibility to do so? @Frohlich

Comment: You want to control a scene from Unity without using Unity's API? I see no problems using Application.LoadLevel() from android eclipse project but you need to add this scenes on your Build Settings in Unity Editor before you can load them... It's not clear to me where you are having problems =/

Comment: You can already run your project from eclipse right? You did import as an integrated android project correctly or is there your problem?

Comment: my problem is that I dont know how to control and acces to Unity API from eclipse,
In other words, what is the code I should enter in the Buttons' script in eclipse to control the scenes?
Where should I enter Application.LoadLevel(); in my android project? @Frohlich